# Solidity ^0.6.0 Truffle Compile Error: Cannot read property ... of undefined

Tags: solidity, truffle-compile, solidity-0.6.x

I initalised a new truffle project by using `truffle init`.

I changed the solc version to ^0.6.0 in the truffle-config.js file.

I ran `truffle compile` and got this error:

```
TypeError: Error parsing C:/init-truffle/contracts/Migrations.sol: Cannot read property 'addFunction' of undefined
    at runWithReadCallback (C:\Users\Lino\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\solc\wrapper.js:37:1)
    at compileStandard (C:\Users\Lino\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\solc\wrapper.js:78:1)
    at Object.compileStandardWrapper (C:\Users\Lino\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\solc\wrapper.js:85:1)
    at Object.parseImports (C:\Users\Lino\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-compile\parser.js:47:1)
    at Object.getImports (C:\Users\Lino\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-compile\profiler.js:374:1)
    at Promise.all.then.results (C:\Users\Lino\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-compile\profiler.js:346:1)
Truffle v5.0.5 (core: 5.0.5)
Node v10.16.3
```

Here is the Migration.sol file:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }
}
```

Here is the 1_initial_migration.js file:

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

Does anyone know what to do? This file compile without any problems with solc version set to ^0.5.0.

Environment:

- Operating System: Windows 10
- Truffle v5.0.5 (core: 5.0.5)
- Node v10.16.3

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a problem from your JS code. please add your JS/Web3js code.

Comment: I added the only JS file automatically created by Truffle when running `truffle init`
I modified noting more than the solidity compiler version, so there is no web3js code.

Comment: Could be an issue with Truffle which you can report at https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues.

Comment: Which version of truffle are you using?

Answer (score 8):

Turn out that `Truffle v5` versions earlier than `v5.1.5` won't successfully compile `^0.6.0` solidity contracts, because the solc wrapper Truffle used (directly from solc-js) was only compatible with `^0.5.0` contracts.

The solution is to update the truffle package using `npm update -g truffle`

Thanks to CruzMolina from GitHub !