# Truffle's artifact is undefined when running truffle migrate

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, typescript

I'm trying to run `truffle migrate` on two js files: `1_initial_migration.js` and `2_deploy_contracts.js`. I can successfully compile my `.sol` files to `.json` ABIs but then when I try to `migrate` I get the following error:

```bash
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'require' of undefined
```

Here's how I've utilised `artifacts` in my js files:

```js
const { artifacts } = require("truffle");
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");
```

`truffle version` results are as follows:

```bash
Truffle v5.1.39 (core: 5.1.39)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v14.16.0
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

Also I'm following [this course on youtube](https://youtu.be/CgXQC4dbGUE?t=1399).

I've seen a couple of posts about changing solitidy version, solc(?) version, and truffle version. I've tried downgrading my global truffle version to 5.1.39 and upgrading the solidity version at the start of my `.sol` files to ^0.6.0, as that seems to be the recommendations from those posts:

[Solidity ^0.6.0 Truffle Compile Error: Cannot read property ... of undefined](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84388/solidity-0-6-0-truffle-compile-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/4191

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vs-Code, the editor might give an error that artifact is not defined if you remove this line:

`const { artifacts } = require("truffle");`

But if you run truffle compile, the contract will compile successfully as the artifact is globally available since you have installed truffle globally in your system.

Just add `// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef` to remove that error and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Ammar's solution works for me, thanks a lot

replaced

```
const { artifacts } = require("truffle");
```

to

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
```

and migrated successfully